# Raphael JS: how to find path of an SVG image?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Using GIMP I have obtained path of each continent in http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Continents.svg but now I am not able to figure out how to convert this SVG file into something like (picked from https://github.com/thomaspeklak/raphaeljs-worldmap):

Can you please guide me how I can convert the SVG path to Raphael Path ?

```
africa.push(W.path("M13728 10231 c-34 -19 -84 -21 -109 -5 -6 4 -15 1 -19 -5 -5 -9 -14 -9 -35 1 -22 10 -29 10 -33 0 -2 -6 -11 -12 -21 -12 -9 0 -23 -6 -29 -12 -10 -10 -17 -10 -32 0 -27 16 -55 15 -190 -7 -113 -19 -180 -42 -180 -63 0 -5 -7 -8 -15 -5 -8 4 -17 2 -20 -3 -4 -6 -13 -10 -21 -10 -8 0 -26 -11 -40 -25 -14 -14 -30 -25 -37 -26 -25 -2 -62 3 -70 10 -4 4 -33 4 -65 0 -63 -9 -100 6 -109 42 -6 20 -20 24 -39 11 -6 -4 -22 -32 -35 -62 -34 -81 -57 -108 -119 -137 -60 -29 -120 -82 -120 -107 0 -9 -10 -31 -22 -47 -18 -24 -23 -44 -23 -94 0 -38 -5 -69 -12 -76 -7 -7 -13 -18 -13 -24 0 -5 -16 -24 -36 -40 -20 -17 -45 -38 -56 -48 -23 -21 -80 -47 -103 -47 -22 0 -36 -16 -62 -72 -13 -27 -27 -48 -31 -48 -27 0 -82 -82 -82 -123 0 -24 ")
  )
  .attr(attr)
  .scale(0.016963, -0.016963, 0,0)
  .translate(0,-15000);
```

-Thank you

Comment: I have tried GIMP to output svg path but it looks different from what Raphael path.

Comment: Would you screenshot what you're getting, or create a jsfiddle, so people can see your current progress easily?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you're working with vectors, so you're likely to get better results in [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) ('the open source Adobe Illustrator') than gimp ('the open source Adobe Photoshop').

A good first step would be import it into Inkscape, use whatever Inkscape's equivalent of Illustrator's path simplify tool is (assuming low file size is more important than the very high level of detail in most wikipedia SVG maps - be careful that it doesn't break country borders), and export as SVG. You might also want to give each country shape an appropriate ID (e.g. country name or country code) within Inkscape if they don't already have one already, to save time later.

Then to turn that into Raphael logic, there's three options:

1. Use [Ready Set Raphael (rsr)](http://readysetraphael.com) which is a **free SVG to raphael converter** web service. Unless rsr has been updated since I wrote this, you'll probably want to tidy up the resulting code:

   - Putting it all in a set that works, by putting [`paper.setStart();`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setStart) before and `var world = paper.setFinish();` after the block of paths (don't forget to substitute `paper` for whatever you're using).
   - Replace-all away all the duplicated `.attr()`s except for any that set id, then apply `attr()`s like fill and stroke to the set, rather than each individual element.
   - Store your paths in an object for easy access by name. Makes working with Raphael so much easier.
2. Use **some other SVG to Raphael converter** or importer (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import)). I don't know if these are any good, I've personally had better experiences with Ready Set Raphael.
3. Just **do it by hand**. This can be as simple as copying and pasting the string from `d="lots of co-ordinates"` from each SVG path into something like `var someCountry = paper.path("lots of co-ordinates"); someSet.push(someCountry);`. It will be time consuming since there are so many countries (170 or so) but the extra control might save time in the long run.

And don't forget to [learn from examples](http://raphaeljs.com/world/).

Comment: It's really neat, but don't be over-reliant on RSR. When I first used it, I was like, "Great, I don't need to spend time figuring out exactly what's going on with these paths and sets!". Then everything I tried didn't work. Turned out it was because I didn't know exactly what was going on with those paths and sets. The way it sets out the code is okay for most cases, but that tends to mean not quite ideal for any one specific case. Good for getting started and seeing how things work.

Comment: agree. you should definitely know what you're using before you dive all the way in. luckily for me, i've been using raphael for a while ;) for me, this will be super helpful for getting custom svg text (that isn't already a font) into raphael format. great find!

Comment: Regarding your 'Do it by hand' method: I am happy to take this approach, however, isn't there a difference between svg coordinates and Raphael's? For example, it seems as though svg permits negative coordinate numbers whereas Raphael is all positive numbers given that it originates in the top left corner. If I am correct, how does one translate that?

Comment: Negative co-ordinates are fine in Raphael, they simply take things past the top left corner