# Import SVG Path Data into Raphael.js

Tags: html, raphael

I'm messing around with [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) and would like to import some `SVG` into Raphael Objects. I've checked some twitter posts from https://twitter.com/RaphaelJS where he is saying that you can copy and paste the path points and use them. Unfortanetly I can't get it to work.

What I would simply like to do is this simple svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="841.89px" height="595.28px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 595.28" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 595.28" xml:space="preserve">
<polyline fill="#CBBBA0" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="272.343,345.194 307.418,535.492 349.955,342.955 "/>
<circle fill="#E30613" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="277.194" cy="282.881" r="62.313"/>
</svg>
```

into Raphael-Objects. Maybe you have some ideas how to solve this.

I thought it could be possible like this:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
paper.path(["272.343,345.194 307.418,535.492 349.955,342.955"])
```

bummer! Doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're looking at a polygon / polyline, not a path.

Convert the `polyline` `points` to a `path` `d` (definition) [using something like in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717190/convert-svg-polygon-to-path). Then you'll get a path string that Raphael understands.

You can spot path definitions as opposed to polygon or polyline defintions because [path strings always start with `M`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231523/will-a-raphael-svg-path-definition-always-start-with-m-and-if-not-will-su).

---

For convenience, here's a JSBIN demo of the code on that above linked question where you can copy and paste in and convert any SVG polygons or polylines:

### http://jsbin.com/avuzas/1/edit

Comment: very nice workaround. Thank you for that, but then comes one question up again. Is there something similar for circles or ellipses, or do I have to make that per hand? eg. use `attr()` and fill it with the circle values and so on?

Comment: There are a few tools that automatically convert SVG into Raphael, I wrote up a few in an answer to a question ages ago... here it is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452247/raphael-js-how-to-find-path-of-an-svg-image